# Moving parent by moving a child

Tags: rigging

To help myself with rigging my dinosaur properly i downloaded a nice, professional  [dino](http://www.cadnav.com/3d-models/model-19554.html) with a nice rig. I found out in it the thing i don't understand. There's a parent-child chain: chest -> neck -> head -> jaw and there's no bone constraints on any of those bones... and somehow you move the head and the neck follows. It works like IK and it's very smooth and it's comfortable but i have no idea how it's done, despite of having the .blend file.

My question is: how to do this?

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible to answer without seeing the file. It could be any number of things based on your description.

Comment: there's the link in my question.
http://www.cadnav.com/3d-models/model-19554.html

Comment: I don't see the download link. Its buried in the 100 ads on that page. Use Blender SE hosting please: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I am not able to put a direct link to a file because it's being run by a script on the site. so... there's a big  'download' button under the description.
i wanted to see how the site is looking without adblock turned on and i see very few and very small ads.

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3629/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey that took me awhile because I'm also used to looking for bone constraints. I guess the file creator got lazy and just used auto IK in the tool shelf. It is just a check box enabled.

Here is a screen shot of the option.
[image: Auto IK]

Comment: Yep. That's the thing. I never used it but, on this example, seems to work pretty fine.